Is Homelander's obsession with human milk public knowledge?
In The Boys, season 4 episode 6 Dirty Business, Firecracker attracts Homelander's attention by spreading his face with her milk.
When asked by Homelander, "You are not pregnant", Firecracker replies that she has been taking a drug that enlarges her heart a little and enable her to produce milk; which means she has been preparing to feed Homelander with her milk for sometime.
As the most famous superhero, Homelander would be really careful to hide his human milk obsession from the public. A-Train looks surprised when he tries to steal Compound-V from Homelander's private residence, which suggests for a member of the Seven such as A-Train, it is indeed a secret.
How does Firecracker, a new member of the Seven and a member who has not earned any trust from Homelander, knows about Homelander's obsession?

Homelander's obsession with human milk might not be as secret as we initially thought. In fact, there's evidence that this information has been circulating within Vought.
In Season 4, Episode 2, "Life Among the Septics," Sage, a supe who is considered the world's smartest person, says to Ashley Barrett:

You're so afraid of [Homelander], you've plucked yourself bald. If I were you, I'd make myself useful. You know, get some lactation going, let him suck on those t-----s. Before you end up like Madelyn Stillwell.

Sage's superhuman observation and deduction skills are on full display here. Not only does she correctly deduce that Ashley's baldness (hidden beneath a wig) is stress-induced, but she also seems to have pieced together Homelander's milk obsession and his role in Madelyn Stillwell's death.
This scene suggests that at least two people within Vought are aware of Homelander's proclivity. It's not a stretch to imagine that this information could have spread further, possibly reaching Firecracker's ears through the grapevine or, likely, a similar conversation with Sage.
